# Clearing Tile updates on Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 application which has to update tiles based on certain conditions like WiFi available, content exists in the knownfolders, etc...

During each Background task cycle i do something like this,

```
EnableNotificationQueue();
ClearTile();
CheckWiFi();//posts a notification saying Wifi is Present or not
CheckKnownFolderesContent();//posts a notifications with file count
```

This essentially creates a Notification queue of upto 5 tile notifications and clears the previous tile and post a tile notification accordingly.

What i am trying to understand is if it is possible to just update a tile notification which is already in the queue. For example: One background task create two notifications 1. No Wifi 2. 5 files in the folder.

Is it possible to just update the 2nd tile with new count by not clearing the other tile which already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. This can be done using tags.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868234(v=win.10)